# Отправка запроса на сервер

Tags: ajax

Используя Json язык для передачи, каким лучшим и правильным образом отправлять данные клиента на сервер для их дальнейшей обработки?

Answer (score 1):

> **Используя Json язык для передачи**

Удачи! если ты нашел такой язык!

А вообще почитать про **формат** можно [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

[json-decode.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
[json-encode](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.json-encode.html)

Answer (score 0):

А лучше даже тут [json.org](http://www.json.org/)